# Converting png thumbnail to jpg

Tags: javascript, image, png, thumbnails

I have a png thumbnail with base64 data. I am trying to convert it to jpeg thumbnail.
I am not sure what am I doing wrong. My current item has a blank thumbnail

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.id = currItem.Id + '_1';
canvas.width = currItem.ThumbnailInfo[0].Width;
canvas.height = currItem.ThumbnailInfo[0].Height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  var img = new Image();
  img.src = currItem.ThumbnailInfo[0].Thumbnail;
  img.onload = async function () {
    await ctx!.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var imageData = ctx?.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx?.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //var imageData = canvas.toDataURL();
    var imagejpeg = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    resolve(imagejpeg);
  }
});

let imagejpgeg2 = await p;
currItem.ThumbnailInfo[0].Thumbnail = imagejpeg;
```

Comment: You’re waiting for the image to load in order to draw it onto the canvas… but you _read_ the canvas data immediately without waiting for the image to load, let alone the image to be drawn first?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work if I just use an await in onLoad. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure how `await` helps here. `onload` doesn’t return a Promise. Have you tried simply putting the `.toDataURL` calls and everything after them _inside_ the `onload` callback?

Comment: I use this now, but I get a blank thumbnail

Comment: You are now literally drawing a black rectangle over the image you just did draw. What did you expect `ctx?.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` to do? Remove this line and the one before, you don't need that `getImageData` here. (Also `drawImage` is synchronous, no need to `await` for it.)

Answer (score -1):

You may use Javascript JIMP Library to process Images.(PNG to JPG)
you should take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp